# Split VMWare's Hard Drive

Tags: vmware-workstation

I've got a virtual machine with an 8 gig hard drive in one file.  I want to now split virtual hard drive into 2 gig chunks so I can copy the VM onto a FAT32 drive.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This can be done](http://communities.vmware.com/message/976835;jsessionid=E2D2F2CF63AB64CB16B6CF44BF78EFB7#976835) using the vmware-vdiskmanager.exe program

Quote from [www.luisrocha.net](http://www.luisrocha.net/2008/11/splitting-your-vmware-virtual-disk-into.html):

> 1. For a growable virtual disk, use the following command to split into 2 GB:
>
> `vmware-vdiskmanager.exe -r old.vmdk -t 1 new.vmdk or`
>
> 2. For a preallocated virtual disk, use the following command to split in 2 GB:
>
> `vmware-vdiskmanager.exe -r old.vmdk -t 3 new.vmdk`

Also see:

[VMWare Server FAQs](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-1160;jsessionid=E2D2F2CF63AB64CB16B6CF44BF78EFB7) (Look for "What are the pros and cons of the different disk types"

Comment: This is of course assuming you are using VMware's workstation product.  Some of the other products use a utility known as "vmkfstools", but the general concept is the same.

Comment: My VMware Server 2 machine also has `vmware-vdiskmanager`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the only way to do that would be to download the VMware converter and use that to migrate to a new virtual machine which is configured for 2 Gig files.

It would probably be easier to simply convert the destination hard drive to NTFS.

Comment: This is overkill. You can easily convert an existing disk without creating a whole new virtual machine.

Comment: Oh, excellent.  Didn't know you could split the disk like that.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mess with the .vmdk I'd strongly advise you to use RAR or ZIP to compress and split the single file into multiple <2GB files - then expand them at their destination - that way you're not fiddling with the actual VM, just packing it differently for transportation.

Comment: No, I think it now needs to reside on a FAT32 drive -- so he can't expand it on a FAT32 partition because it can't handle files this large.

Answer (score -1):

haven't tried splitting virtual disk but I think that won't be complicated. I used to split HDD with partitionguru and I remember this tool supports virtual disks generated by Vmware. Since it's a free tool, you may as well have a try